# Rails Pass A Parameter To Conditional Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I'm importing heaps of student data from an spreadsheet document. Each row of student data will represent a new user, however, the possibility of importing an already existing student exists and I want to bypass some of my user validations such as username uniqueness accordingly so that I can build associations for both new and existing records, but only if they're being imported to the same school.

Thus far I have the following validation setup in my User model:

**user.rb**

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username, :unless => :not_unique_to_school?

def not_unique_to_school?
  user = find_by_username(self.username)
  user.present? && user.school_id == 6
end
```

Now how would I go about replacing that 6 with a value I have access to in the controller? Instructors will be the ones handling the importing and they'll be importing students to their school so I would typically run current_user.school_id to retrieve the school id that I want them to be imported to, but I don't have access to the current_user helper in my model.

I'm not concerned about duplicating usernames as I'll be handling that on a different step, this is just the preliminary validation.

---

**Edit**

Simplified school & user model:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :username, 
                  :first_name, :last_name, :school_id, :roles_mask

  belongs_to :school

  validates_presence_of :username, :on => :create, :message => "can't be blank"
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :unless => :unique_to_school?

  def unique_to_school?
    user = find_by_username(self.username)
    user.present? && user.school_id == 6
  end 

  def find_by_username(username)
    User.where(:username => username).first
  end     

end
```

**school.rb**

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :country_id, :name, :state_id

  has_many :users    

end
```

Comment: Can you post your whole User model and School model?

Comment: and your controller might be useful too.

Comment: Trust me you don't want my whole User and School model, there's a lot of irrelevant complexity going on in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me:

```
validate :user_cant_be_duplicate_in_other_schools  

def user_cant_be_duplicate_in_other_schools
    errors.add(:username, :taken) if User.count(:conditions => ["school_id != ? AND username = ?", self.school_id, self.username]) > 0
end
```

As opposed to testing if a User belongs to a particular school we're testing for the lack of belonging to a particular school. I didn't come up with this answer, another user posted this as an answer but deleted it shortly after for reasons unknown.

Answer (score 4):

I'd add a method to your School model:

```
def student_named?(name)
  self.users.where(:username => name).any?
end
```

then in your validation:

```
def not_unique_to_school?
  self.school.student_named?(self.username)
end
```

Comment: This produces `Unknown key: username` for me in the resulting redirect. I can't determine if it's coming from the School model or the User model.

Comment: Sorry, `.find` should have been `.where`, try the edited code.

Comment: Works great now, thanks for the quick response. I wish that other user hadn't deleted his answer as that also worked for me with a couple of minor modifications.

Comment: Sorry, but I might have jumped the gun on this as I thought it was working initially but that doesn't seem to be the case. Looking at the code now there's nothing to distinguish between the current school that students are being added to and the `self.school` in the not_unique_to_school? method. In fact, if you're testing to see if a child's parent contains the child wouldn't that always return true? I have a working validation that that other user had posted and removed shortly after if you want to see what I mean.